# How i can upload tow image in a form Shopware 6

Tags: shopware

i a m new in **Shopware** . I developed a plugin in my plugin i need upload two image in a form .

I can drag a pic from **Sidebar media** in second input media and save it with out any problem.
but my problem is there .i can not upload pic in second upload.this is my code .how i can do it?

```
  <sw-card v-if="blog" :isLoading="isLoading" :title="$t('ak-blog.detail.section.image')">
            <sw-upload-store-listener :uploadTag="blog.id" @media-upload-finish="onSetMediaItem" autoUpload></sw-upload-store-listener>
            <sw-media-upload :label="$tc('ak-blog.detail.label.imageBig')" variant="regular"
                             :source="mediaItem" :uploadTag="blog.id" :allowMultiSelect="false"
                             @media-drop="onMediaDropped"
                             @media-upload-sidebar-open="openMediaSidebar"
                             @media-upload-remove-image="onRemoveMediaItem">
            </sw-media-upload>
        </sw-card>

         <sw-card v-if="blog" :isLoading="isLoading" :title="$t('ak-blog.detail.section.image')">
            <sw-upload-store-listener :uploadTag="blog.id" @media-upload-finish="onSetMediaItemImageSmall" autoUpload></sw-upload-store-listener>
            <sw-media-upload :label="$tc('ak-blog.detail.label.imageSmall')" variant="regular"
                             :source="mediaItemImageSmall" :uploadTagSmallImage="blog.id" :allowMultiSelect="false"
                             @media-drop="onMediaDroppedImageSmall"
                             @media-upload-sidebar-open="openMediaSidebarImageSmall"
                             @media-upload-remove-image="onRemoveMediaItemImageSmall">
            </sw-media-upload>
        </sw-card>
```

Comment: So which error do you get within your console? Please provide as many information as possible and please ask a proper question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i don't get any error .i check console but there is not anything. actually when i upload pic pic appearance in form.but doesn't save in my database. i guess my problem is uploadTag method..i don't know how i can define another uploadTag for second input form.

Comment: i try to find a plugin has my situation.( upload tow pic in a form) but i can not find any thing.

Comment: How does your method(s) look like? Please provide proper informations.
Where is the image saved? An entity extension?

Comment: i know about entity .i define an entity and i can save some data like title,name,subject ...also i define a filed for save image article.in my plugin i define tow filed for save pic for each article .large pic and small pic.for this i need to define two input in a form.one of them save correctly .but  about another one i have a problem.do you know a plugin has tow input upload file in a form?